# Is it possible to make a flight controller with a non real-time OS?

Tags: raspberry-pi, real-time, windows-10-iot-core

I've been reading that Raspberry Pi is not suitable for a flight controller because Raspbian (or in my case Windows 10 IoT) is not a real-time OS.

I've read that non real-time OSs are not suitable for critical applications like medical devices, military devices, airplanes, etc.

What is the worst that can happen if I use a Raspberry Pi as quadcopter flight controller? Is it a big deal if the drone reacts to my input a few milliseconds late?

Comment: It will matter a lot if the response time for one command is 1ms and the response time for the next command is 150ms, then the response time for the third command is 2500ms. It's not a constant delay between command and execution, it varies widely and can (and does) change continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Even Windows 10 does not natively support real-time operation, some third-party extensions may provide developers with the solution they need to take full advantage of Windows 10's capabilities, while meeting their application's real-time requirements. You can search 'Drone Pi: A Windows 10 Raspberry Pi 4G Drone', it is a good sample for flight controller. You can also try to use Arduino  + Raspberry Pi as a solution.

Comment: I've seen that example on Hackstr and I also found IntervalZero RTX extension, but it only works with Windows 10 IoT Enterprise and MinnowBoard (because of x86 architecture). I wanted to know that are these few millisecond delays a big deal for a simple drone project?

Comment: Saying "Even Windows 10" is a bit disingenuous, as if Windows 10 were some sort of solution to anything other than how bad WIndows 9, 8, 7, ... were.   If it represents some sort of apex of the Windows family, that is welcome news; but hardly a ringing endorsement.   Some vendors used windows to deploy minor process control functions like plc front ends; but I think stuxnet proved to the world how not up to the job it was.